# What happens to the time slice if you disable preemption in vxWorks?

Tags: vxworks

If you have round robin scheduling enabled in VxWorks, and you use taskLock() to disable preemption, what happens when your timeslice expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When preemption is disabled via taskLock, the timeslice counter will not increment. Your timeslice will never expire until preemption is re-enabled.